# How to address ssh-server with a subdomain for remote access?

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, openssh

I am trying to set up ssh-server on my Ubuntu 12.04 VM (running in VirtualBox on Mac OS X 10.7).

I have a domain name, call it foo.com, and I'd like to make ssh available via ssh to linux.foo.com. (I want this to be accessible from outside the local network.)

How can I do this? Do I need a static IP address or is there a way to dynamically forward traffic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to add an "A" record for linux.foo.com to the name servers for foo.com pointing to the public IP of your machine/home router.
2. If that public IP is dynamic, you need a tool and an interface (API) that will allow automatic updating; most name servers provided by domain-name resellers or hosting services don't have such dynamic DNS functionality, so you may be better off with a dynamic DNS service such as DynDNS. With a paid account, I believe they will let you use your own domain/subdomain. linux.foo.com with their name servers.
3. If your VM is connected in bridged mode, your router needs to be set up to forward port 22 to its internal IP.

   - If it's in NAT, you need to configure vbox and the host to do this forwarding.

Comment: I see. My domain is hosted by GoDaddy currently so I doubt I have the dynamic DNS functionality you mentioned in (2).
Do you think [Zerigo Free](http://zerigo.com/managed-dns/pricing) would have sufficient features?

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate upon step 2... what do I need to do, given the API? Thanks!